# How can I show all time between 2 different time parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 Columns in db Time Parameter(00:15) , StartTime(09:00) , EndTime (15:00)

Now I want to show all time with gap of 00:15 min between 09:00 and 15:00

What query should I write so that it returns values something like this:

```
09:00 - 09:15
09:15 - 09:30
09:30 - 09:45
-
-
-
-
14:45 - 15:00
```

Comment: you have a whole table full of these rows with parameters, start times, and end times, right?  or do you only need a solution for this one example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using CTE and assuming `hour part of @time is zero`:

```
declare @time time(0) = '00:15', 
        @start time(0) = '12:00', 
        @end time(0) = '15:00'

;with cte as (
    select @start sTime, dateadd(minute, datepart(minute,@time), @start) eTime
    union all
    select eTime, dateadd(minute, datepart(minute,@time), eTime)
    from cte
    where dateadd(minute, datepart(minute,@time), eTime) <= @end
)
select left(sTime,5) + ' - ' + left(eTime, 5) results 
from cte

--results
12:00 - 12:15
12:15 - 12:30
12:30 - 12:45
12:45 - 13:00
13:00 - 13:15
13:15 - 13:30
13:30 - 13:45
13:45 - 14:00
14:00 - 14:15
14:15 - 14:30
14:30 - 14:45
14:45 - 15:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Common table expression (CTE)  to generate a table with all the times in it that you want.

```
Declare @strtDt smallDatetime = '15 May 2013 09:00';
Declare @endDt smallDateTime = '15 May 2013 15:00';
With DateTimes(dt) As
    (Select @strtDt
      Union All
     Select DateAdd(minute, 15, dt)
     From DateTimes
     Where dt < @endDt) 
Select dt from DateTimes 
option (maxrecursion 10000)
```