# Display all time between two different time with parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

Something like this

```
Gap : 30 min
Time A : 12:00
Time B : 15:00
```

Result

```
12:00-12:30
12:30-13:00
13:00-13:30
13:30-14:00
13:00-14:30
13:30-15:00
```

Same thing is asked in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652509/how-can-i-show-all-time-between-2-different-time-parameter) But i need this in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use tally table and adding multiple 30 minutes `INTERVAL`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timeA + INTERVAL n * 30 MINUTE, '%k:%i') as timeA,
       DATE_FORMAT(timeA + INTERVAL (n+1) * 30 MINUTE , '%k:%i') as timeB,
       CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(timeA + INTERVAL n * 30 MINUTE, '%k:%i'),'-',
       DATE_FORMAT(timeA + INTERVAL (n+1) * 30 MINUTE , '%k:%i')) as time_range
FROM tab
CROSS JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
) n
WHERE timeA + INTERVAL (n+1) * 30 MINUTE <= timeB
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63f8f/11/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║ timeA  ║ timeB  ║ time_range  ║
╠════════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║ 12:00  ║ 12:30  ║ 12:00-12:30 ║
║ 12:30  ║ 13:00  ║ 12:30-13:00 ║
║ 13:00  ║ 13:30  ║ 13:00-13:30 ║
║ 13:30  ║ 14:00  ║ 13:30-14:00 ║
║ 14:00  ║ 14:30  ║ 14:00-14:30 ║
║ 14:30  ║ 15:00  ║ 14:30-15:00 ║
╚════════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

---

With variables and support of non-alligned gap:

```
SET @gap = 45;
SET @start = '11:00:00';
SET @end = '15:00:00';
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(timeA + INTERVAL n * @gap MINUTE, '%k:%i'),'-',
       DATE_FORMAT(IF(timeA + INTERVAL (n+1) * @gap MINUTE < timeB,
                      timeA + INTERVAL (n+1) * @gap MINUTE,
                      timeB) , '%k:%i')) as time_range
FROM 
  (SELECT CAST(@start AS TIME) AS timeA, CAST(@end AS TIME) AS timeB) AS tab
CROSS JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
) n
WHERE timeA + INTERVAL (n) * @gap MINUTE <= timeB
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63f8f/21/3)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════════╗
║ time_range  ║
╠═════════════╣
║ 11:00-11:45 ║
║ 11:45-12:30 ║
║ 12:30-13:15 ║
║ 13:15-14:00 ║
║ 14:00-14:45 ║
║ 14:45-15:00 ║     -- not 15.30
╚═════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the SEQUENCE Engine you can use this:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    "SELECT CONCAT (
    TIME('11:00') + interval ((seq-1) * 30) Minute,
    ' - ',
    TIME('11:00') + interval (seq * 30) Minute) AS time_range
    FROM seq_1_to_",
    CAST( (TIME_TO_SEC( timediff('13:00','11:00')) /60/30) AS UNSIGNED)
) INTO @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**Output**

```
+---------------------+
| time_range          |
+---------------------+
| 11:00:00 - 11:30:00 |
| 11:30:00 - 12:00:00 |
| 12:00:00 - 12:30:00 |
| 12:30:00 - 13:00:00 |
+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```